# Peer dependency issue in React on Travis CI server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, travis-ci

When attempting to build an application on a Travis CI server, an error returns stating a peer dependency issue as stated below:

```
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer react@"^15" from react-router-dom@4.1.1

npm ERR! node_modules/react-router-dom

npm ERR!   react-router-dom@"^4.1.1" from the root project

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@15.7.0

npm ERR! node_modules/react

npm ERR!   peer react@"^15" from react-router-dom@4.1.1

npm ERR!   node_modules/react-router-dom

npm ERR!     react-router-dom@"^4.1.1" from the root project

npm ERR!
```

I was initially using npm but switched to yarn on the .travis.yml file, to no success.
How do I fix the issue?

Edit: Added package.json

```html
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": {
    "/auth/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.13",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0-alpha.13",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.10",
    "redux": "^3.7.1",
    "redux-form": "^7.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your package.json file as well, in this case it would be helpful to find the correct answer.

Comment: Assuming it works locally, can you verify your CI environment is using the same version Node and npm?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/12d811f56d56e214ca5200140b7e4ec145a84776/packages/react-router-dom/package.json#L40), `react-router-dom` has declared `react` package as a `peerDependencies` with a specific version. Meaning `react-router-dom` expects you to have installed `react` `v15`. But you have installed React `v16.0.0-alpha.13`.

You should downgrade your `react` package or upgrade your `react-router-dom`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that might be the issue but wasn't sure. But there's no way of knowing that downgrading React to v15 will break anything else before I do it, right?

Comment: You can search and read React [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1600-september-26-2017) and look for breaking changes. But I would recommend updating `react-router-dom` to a compatible version instead.